# At least 1 required checkbox in form submit

Tags: javascript

I have a form with many checkbox. User must select at least one of them to submit the form. I've tested other stacks found here without success. This is my HTML code:

```html
<form id="formnewsletter" action="mypage">
  <input name="list" value="1" type="hidden">
  <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required="required" type="email">
  <div class="formphonebox">
    <input class="form-control" id="prefix" name="prefix" value="0039" style="display:inline; width:25%;" type="text"> <input class="form-control" id="number" name="number" value="" placeholder="Cellulare" style="width:70%; float:right" type="text">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="formlistbox">
    <span class="checkbox">
      <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="26" id="group26" name="group" type="checkbox">
      <label for="group26">group26</label>
    </span>
    <span class="checkbox">
      <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="47" id="group47" name="group" type="checkbox">
      <label for="group47">group47</label>
    </span>
    <span class="checkbox">
      <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="41" id="group41" name="group" type="checkbox">
      <label for="group41">group41</label>
    </span>
    <span class="checkbox">
      <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="55" id="group55" name="group" type="checkbox">
      <label for="group55">group55</label>
    </span>
    <span class="checkbox">
      <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="30" id="group30" name="group" type="checkbox">
      <label for="group30">group30</label>
    </span>
    <span class="checkbox">
      <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="58" id="group58" name="group" type="checkbox">
      <label for="group58">group58</label>
    </span>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <span class="checkbox">
    <input id="privacycheck" type="checkbox" required="required">
    <label for="privacycheck"><small><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></small></label>
  </span>
  <div align="center">
    <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Iscrivimi">Iscrivimi</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

UPDATE with solution. This is the script that worked in my case:

```
//controlla che almeno un checkbox delle liste/gruppi newsletter sia flaggato
$(document).ready(function () {

    function checkMe() {
        document.getElementById("formnewsletter").onsubmit = function() {
            //controlla che almeno un checkbox delle liste/gruppi newsletter sia flaggato
            if (document.querySelector('.listchecknewsletter:checked')) {
                // at least one is checked
                } else {
                // none are checked
                alert("Seleziona una lista!");
                return false;
            }

        };
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        checkMe();
    }

});
```

Can someone suggest me the JavaScript code to let it work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't tagged it with `jQuery`, here is a solution in plain ol' javascript.

You can use CSS class of the checkboxes along with [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
if (document.querySelector('.listchecknewsletter:checked')) {
   // at least one is checked
} else {
   // none are checked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with jquery it would work like this for example:

```js
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
var checkboxes = $('.formlistbox input[type="checkbox"]');
   if(checkboxes.filter(':checked').length < 1) {
       alert("please check at least 1 checkbox");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="list" value="1" type="hidden">
<input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required="required" type="email">

<div class="formphonebox">
    <input class="form-control" id="prefix" name="prefix" value="0039" style="display:inline; width:25%;" type="text"> <input class="form-control" id="number" name="number" value="" placeholder="Cellulare" style="width:70%; float:right" type="text">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="formlistbox">

    <span class="checkbox">
        <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="26" id="group26" name="group" type="checkbox">
        <label for="group26">group26</label>
    </span>

    <span class="checkbox">
        <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="47" id="group47" name="group" type="checkbox">
        <label for="group47">group47</label>
    </span>

    <span class="checkbox">
        <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="41" id="group41" name="group" type="checkbox">
        <label for="group41">group41</label>
    </span>

    <span class="checkbox">
        <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="55" id="group55" name="group" type="checkbox">
        <label for="group55">group55</label>
    </span>

    <span class="checkbox">
        <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="30" id="group30" name="group" type="checkbox">
        <label for="group30">group30</label>
    </span>

    <span class="checkbox">
        <input class="listchecknewsletter" value="58" id="group58" name="group" type="checkbox">
        <label for="group58">group58</label>
    </span>

</div>
<hr>
<span class="checkbox">
    <input id="privacycheck" type="checkbox" required="required">
    <label for="privacycheck"><small><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></small></label>
</span>
<div align="center">
    <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Iscrivimi" id="submit">Iscrivimi</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you (want to) use jQuery:

```
if($('.listchecknewsletter:checked').length > 0) {
    // one or more are checked
}
```

Further, if you want to POST all the checkbox values, you have to change their name to group[], to make it an array.